# Block scope, function scope and local scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

1. Is *block scope* sometimes the same as *function scope*? I know *function scope* is for everything inside a function, but don't get what exactly a *block scope* is.
2. For Javascript, is it **currently** recommended to use `let` / `const` instead of `var` for future maintenance? (This was from [Airbnb Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure you really got your questions answered yet:

> Is block scope sometimes the same as function scope? I know function scope is for everything inside a function, but don't get what
>   exactly a block scope is.

**Yes**, a block scope is sometimes the same as a function scope.  Block scope is everything inside a set of braces `{ a block scope here }`.  So, at the top of a function's code, a block scope will be the same as a function scope:

```
function test(x) {
   // this is both a block scope and a function scope
   let y = 5;
   if (x) {
       // this is a smaller block scope that is not the same as the function scope
       let z = 1;
   }
}
```

> For Javascript, is it currently recommended to use let / const instead
>   of var for future maintenance? (This was from Airbnb Style Guide)

`let` and `const` are part of the newest ES6 specification and are only implemented in the latest Javascript engines and sometimes in the latest engines they are only enabled with special flags.  They are coming to all newer JS engines/browsers, but are not widely deployed yet.  Thus, if you are writing Javascript for regular browser consumption across the broad internet, you cannot reliably use `let` and `const` yet.

There are some cases where you can safely program with `let` and `const` now:

1. If you are targeting only a specific Javascript engine and you know that it has support for those features (such as a specific version of nodejs or a plug-in only for a specific version of a specific browser).
2. If you are using a transpiler that will convert your code to code that will run in all browsers.  When using a transpiler, you can write your code using the latest features and the transpiler will "dumb it down" so that your code will work in older browsers by using simulations of the newer features.

If you are programming for an environment where you know that `let` and `const` are supported, then it is advisable to use them as appropriate.  If you declare a variable at the top of your function, then `let` and `var` will do the same thing.

If you declare a variable in a smaller scope within the function, then `let` will be contained within the smaller scope, but `var` will be hoisted to the top of the function and will have function scope, no matter where it is declared.

---

The [AirBnb Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) you linked to is specifically written for an ES6 environment (note there is a separate link for an ES5 version of their style guide).  So, that means that they are assuming an ES6 capable environment.  That's either because they are targeting a server-side JS engine that they know supports ES6 or because they are using a transpiler that will convert ES6 code into something that will run on an ES5 engine.

---

**A note about transpilers.**  Before using a transpiler and switching all variable declarations to `let` within block scopes, it is worth understanding what kind of code the transpiler generates and whether the extra code it generates has any effect on the performance of your application.  For example, block scope for `let` is simulated by creating an inline IIFE which can lead to extra run-time overhead for every block that contains a `let` statement.  I'm not saying this is necessarily a bad thing that should keep you from using a transpiler, but when deciding whether to use a transpiler, I'd suggest that you thoroughly familiarize yourself with what the transpiled code looks like for a variety of ES6 features so you know whether it is the right tool for any job you have or only for some jobs.

Answer (score 7):

1. javascript 5 does not use blocked scope it uses chained scope. the main difference is that you cannot access the variable out side of the scope unless you make it global. ES 6 will have blocked scope when you declare a variable with let.
2. currently recommended to use var because ES 6 is not fully supported.

Comment: Is there estimated date for release of ES6? I wonder why Airbnb recommended that we use standard of ES6 this early.

Comment: @ChenghuaYang: There have been estimated release dates for the ES6 *specification* for a few years now, I think at one point it was meant to be done in 2012 or 2013. Last I heard, yes, they were expecting it to be this year. But then of course, you have to wait for the vendors to support it, and for people to upgrade their browsers. As for Airbnb, well, maybe they're transpiling, or maybe they're just pushing an agenda.

Comment: @ChenghuaYang Airbnb teams already code in ES6, but they use transpiler (like [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or [Babel](http://babeljs.io/)) to transpile to ES5 so that their code can be used in today's browsers.

Answer (score 4):

> Is block scope sometimes the same as function scope? I know function scope is for everything inside a function, but don't get what exactly a block scope is.

Block scope is everything in side a *block*, e.g.:

```
function foo() {
    // function scope
    if (condition) {
        // block scope
    }
}
```

Up through the 5th edition spec, JavaScript didn't have block scope. The next spec (ECMAScript 6, aka "ES6"), which is very nearly completed, adds block scope via `let` and `const`.

> For Javascript, is it currently recommended to use `let` / `const` instead of var for future maintenance?

That's purely up to you. `let` and `const` are new tools you can add to your belt. They don't *have* to replace `var` if you don't want them to. That said, you hear "`let` is the new `var`" a lot.

Variables declared with `let` have block scope, ones declared with `var` do not.

Note that `let` and `const` [don't have great support in the wild yet](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#let). No great surprise, adding block scope to an engine that never had it before is presumably non-trivial. You can use a transpiler like Babel, or just keep using `var` for now.