# Using const as loop variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I understand the behavior of using `var` and `let` in `for` loop in `typescript`/`javascript` but can someone explain why and how a const variable as a loop variable behaves ?

```
for (const i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, 100 * i);
}
```

From what i understand , when you declare a variable as `const` and initialize its value , the value cannot be changed

Yet you can see the value being changed in the `console.log()` .An error has to be thrown while compilation right ?What am i missing here ?

I have created 2 examples for this behavior .

[Loop variable as a const](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loop-variable-as-const)

[Const variable re assignment](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gzdfm)

Can someone help me understand this ?

Comment: both`const` and `let` have block scope and is hoisted at the top of the block its defined in, the only difference between `const` and `let` is variables declared `const` cannot be reinitialized

Comment: this is a beautiful example of that JS not really has things like `constants`. You are right, this will show an IDE and during building processes but during the runtime JS will just reassign that "const"

Comment: Please include all code in the question itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: @messerbill a real ES2015 environment does actually have constants.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i would have included the code but i wouldn't be able to show the behavior if it wasn't a stackblitz example . I hope you understand where i'm getting at

Comment: If that was the case, and you know the behavior was only replicable in Stackblitz, then you should mention that in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works in Stackblitz because it is running traspiled code:

```
AppComponent.prototype.test = function () {
    var _loop_1 = function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, 100 * i);
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        _loop_1(i);
    }
};
```

It won't work if you add a snippet here because it is not transpiled

```js
for (const i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, 100 * i);
}
```

[image]

Comment: looks like i shouldn't trust stackblitz much or i don't understand how stackblitz works . Thanks a lot for clearing the doubt .so i was correct in assuming that the loop will break.

Comment: @CruelEngine tbf, it does show the red squiggly line under `i++` with error message: "*Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a constant or a read-only property.*"

Comment: and yet it compiled and that is where i was a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question,

```
  test(){
    for(const i =0 ; i< 5; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
      },100*i);
    }
  }
```

This code essentially becomes,

```
  test(){

    // can be only initialized once
    const i;
    for(i = 0 ; i< 5; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
      },100*i);
    }
  }
```

Because every JavaScript variable is [hoisted](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) at the top of its scope, in this case the `test()` as its `const` variable that's why its hoisted in that block and not accessible outside of it.

To correct the piece of the code:

```
  test(){

    // can be only multiple times in that block
    for(let i = 0 ; i< 5; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
      },100*i);
    }
  }
```

Which becomes,

```
  test(){

    let i;
    // can be only multiple times in that block
    for(i = 0 ; i< 5; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
      },100*i);
    }
  }
```

As both `const` and `let` have [block scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705116/block-scope-function-scope-and-local-scope-in-javascript) and is hoisted at the top of the block its defined in, the only difference between `const` and `let` is variables declared const cannot be reinitialized.

Comment: hoisting has nothing to do with this behavior right ? the loop should never run if i declare the loop variable of const

Comment: @CruelEngine you cannot increment a `const` variable once initialized

Comment: yes exactly and yet the code ran in the example i attached in the question

Comment: @CruelEngine I think webpack is transpiling the code to ES3 to maintain compatibility which didnt had `const` and `let` and the `const` is converted to `var`. Anyway you can inspect the transpiled file in the dist folder.